# how can I see what TYPE of data is in my macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have the following code that doesn't work inside a macro:

```
count = Application.Sheets.count
ans = type(count)
msgbox("count is " & ans)
```

but this doesn't work cause I think type is looking for a cell value, how can I get the type of data when using a macro? is there a different function that returns the value in a macro? I have googled this and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you're looking for the [TypeName](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TypeName-Function-581cb27e-4faa-45ba-a94b-5d96e43195ff) Function.

A better idea would be to [use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx) `Option Explicit` so all variables are dimensioned with purpose.

Comment: i was using the typename to get the actual types of data so that i could dimension them, then i can use option explicit for my routine. thanks for your help.

Comment: But the TypeName function tells you what the variable is, not what the underlying data is. If the variables were declared, then they'd have a type. Anyway, I don't know what you're working on - maybe you're sifting through someone else's code. Best of luck!

Comment: how can i tell what the underlying data is? isnt that what typename does? and im  working on my own code, got it to cycle through sheets less than one second vs 2-3 seconds. by properly dimming them, it made the routine run faster.

Comment: Yes that's what it does. doh. But it does get finicky depending on the variable's type, if it isn't a variant.

Comment: i think that typename works as expected as it correctly identified what all my variables were (i didnt delcare them when i made the macro) and then let me dimension them. all in all, it made my routine run faster, by 2 seconds and i can have up to 130 estimating sheets in my workbook. so that time savings is a big plus. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it. Use `typename(variable)`, where `variable` is the variable whose type should be returned.

Comment: You can also use the locals window if you're stepping through your code.